# Backup creates basically empty file

Tags: adb, backup

I am very tired of all the Samsung bloatware imposed on me so I am trying to back up my data prior to rooting the phone and cleaning it up.

There are numerous claims on the internet that this is done using this adb command:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all -system -f myBackupAndroid.ab
```

Some also suggested adding backslashes before spaces after the `backup`. That didn't affect my results, which is (basically) empty file:

[image: image description]

This is pretty nasty trap set on anyone who doesn't double check the status of the backup, before doing something like factory reset.

Unless this is intended by android developpers, what did I do wrong? How to get actual backup of android data? I am using android 4.1.2 on Samsung GT-S7710 - which is Galaxy XCover 2 as I found by googling (they are too shy to mention product name in their OS release).

Comment: Your process is mostly correct, although here some general recommendations... after -f supply the full pathname to a file in your user directory, saving it elsewhere is known to cause failure. Always use a password when you backup and restore, the process has been known to fail without one specified. Word of advise though, don't trust an ADB backup, for some reason they fail, a lot, and often won't restore completely regardless of what you do. Best bet is to boot or flash TWRP/CWM and do a full nandroid backup, then save it off the device.

Comment: Well, but doesn't what you recommend require root permissions? Both of the acronyms you mentioned (which I googled) seem to have something to do with flashing roms and other scary stuff.